# Opcode and ModRM for 'call dword ptr [mem32]' question?

Tags: assembly, opcode

Why can't you call a pointer address from the EBP register? What I mean by this is demonstrated in  the follow code pattern.

1. OpCode: '0xFF 0x10' -> CALL DWORD PTR DS:[EAX]
2. OpCode: '0xFF 0x11' -> CALL DWORD PTR DS:[ECX]
3. OpCode: '0xFF 0x12' -> CALL DWORD PTR DS:[EDX]
4. OpCode: '0xFF 0x13' -> CALL DWORD PTR DS:[EBX]
5. OpCode: '0xFF 0x14' -> CALL DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+EDI]
6. OpCode: '0xFF 0x15 0x012345678' -> CALL DWORD PTR DS:[0x012345678]
7. OpCode: '0xFF 0x16' -> CALL DWORD PTR DS:[ESI]
8. OpCode: '0xFF 0x16' -> CALL DWORD PTR DS:[EDI]

'5' is noted in "Intel Instruct manual" but '6' is never directly referred to and it is never explicitly stated that you cannot call it from the EBP register. I know this isn't a useless feature but I was wondering why Intel choose those two registers to utilize, was it just a design choice or is their something I am missing? (I have a guess but I'm curious what the real reason is.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call via EBP, its just encoded differently.  You need the sequence

```
0xff 0x55 0x00
```

The thing is that there's no way to encode EBP without an offset (the above specifies EBP with a byte offset of 0), as the encoding that you'd normally expect to be EBP without an offset (0x15) instead means 32-bit absolute.

Also note your `0xff 0x14` example -- in that case there's a 3rd byte (a SIB byte) that encodes a base register, index register, and a scale factor.   ESP+EDI like your example has a 3rd byte of `0x3c` -- you want the 3rd byte to be `0x24` to get just ESP

As to *why* they chose EBP and ESP as the registers that can't be encoded simply, its because ESP is the stack pointer (so is normally accessed by push/pop instructions) while EBP is the frame pointer, so you rarely want to dereference it directly without an offset.  At least that was the case when the 80386 was designed.